# need help about picker in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

how i can add value behind Strings in picker items for example, when i select a country then that country should select a city which i mention in xaml or in c# code.

my code:

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
List coursesList = new List();

```
    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        MainPicker.Items.Add("{USA");
```

/// now i want when i select USA Then USA should select New York how to do this?

```
    }


    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
  ///
       
        
    }

    private void MainPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var name = MainPicker.Items[MainPicker.SelectedIndex];
       
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your xaml code?

Answer (score 0):

create a class to model your data

```
public class CountryCity
{
   public string Country { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }

   public CountryCity(string Country, string City)
   {
      this.Country = Country;
      this.City = City;
   }
}
```

create your data

```
List<CountryCity> myData = new List<CountryCity>();
myData.Add(new CountryCity("USA,"New York City"));
// add more data
```

assign the data to your Picker

```
MainPicker.ItemsSource = myData;
```

then when an item is selected

```
 private void MainPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is the selected CountryCity object
    var item = (CountryCity)MainPicker.Items[MainPicker.SelectedIndex];
   
    // to get the individual values, use 
    // item.Country or item.City
}
```